# About extending LinearLayout

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

I need to create a View which extends a LinearLayout to contain some standard android widget.
I've created a class MyLinearLayout which extends the LinearLayout class; but now, how can I use it as an element in the xml layout file? I can't get it working and I haven't been able to find info about it and so I'm a bit confused... O.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

```
package com.example;

public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout...
```

in your xml you can use

```
<com.example.MyLinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/MyLayout"
   [rest of attributes go here]
>
[other stuff here]
</com.example.MyLinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to preface it with the package name that you are using.  So, instead of declaring "MyLinearLayout" you would declare "[PackageName].MyLinearLayout".